# Asp.net drop down list value doesnt change within jquery dialog

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a div , within which I have a button and an asp.net dropdownlist. I see that the dropdownlist value doesnt change. ie. If I select 30 from the dropdownlist, the selected value is still shown as the default value which is 15, Same thing happens when I select 1Hr , 2Hrs , 48Hrs etc.

aspx

```
      <div id='one'>
     <asp:LinkButton ID="ConfigureAlerts" OnClick="btnConfigureAlerts_Click" runat="server">Configure Alerts</asp:LinkButton>
    </div>
    <div id="ViewModalPopupDiv2">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="left" ScrollBars="Auto">
                <asp:Button ID="btnGetLogs" runat="server" Text="SendAlerts" OnClick="btnSendAlertEmail_Click"/>
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Set The Alert Email Interval to every :" CssClass="label"
                                    ForeColor="Black"></asp:Label>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
           <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTimeInterval" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" UseSubmitBehavior="false" >
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="15MIN" Value="15"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="30MIN" Value="30"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="1Hr" Value="60"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="2Hrs" Value="120"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="8Hrs" Value="480"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="24Hrs" Value="1440"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="48Hrs" Value="2880"></asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                <br />                
</asp:Panel>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
```

javascript

```
function ViewModelPopup2() {
        $("#ViewModalPopupDiv2").dialog({
                scrollable: true,
                width: 800,
                modal: true
            });
        }
```

aspx.cs

```
protected void btnSendAlertEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            // Code to send email

        }

protected void btnConfigureAlerts_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript
                       (this, this.GetType(), "callScriptFunction", "ViewModelPopup2();", true);
        }
    }
```

Any Suggestions on what I can do ?

Comment: When you say it doesn't change, do you mean on postback or does the dropdown list not physically show the new value you selected?

Comment: the dropdown list does not physically show the new value selected

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you have those AutoPostBack set to true? I don't see you bind any events to those DDL, so you might as well take that off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have AutoPostBack set against the drop down list. Having that set means it's posting back and refreshing the control which causes the default value to be selected.

Comment: Hey thanks ! On removing the autopostback property , I am able to select values from the dropdownlist,  but as soon as I click the button, the dropdownlist again goes back to the initial value

Comment: You need to add something in the page load / postback event that sets the selected value of that drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:button Id=" btnConfigureAlerts" runat="Server" OnClientClick="ViewModelPopup2()"></asp:button>

function ViewModelPopup2() {
        $("#ViewModalPopupDiv2").dialog({
                scrollable: true,
                width: 800,
                modal: true
            });
        };
```